# How to not show start commands on command line when running npm start?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, package.json

In my node.js app, I have a package.json file that has this configuration for the `script.start` property

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo Starting to compile... && node start.js && echo Complete!"
  },
```

Then when I type `npm start` it shows on the command line

```
> my-framework@0.5.5 start C:\app\tools
> echo Starting to compile... && node start.js && echo Complete!
```

Is there a way I can hide this from showing in the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running `npm start`, run `npm start -s`.

I don't think there is any way to do this without passing a flag to `npm start`.